# bashで配列への要素の追加に+=が使えるバージョン

Tags: bash, shellscript, array

シェルスクリプトで配列への要素の追加に`+=`を使うとエラーが出る環境があるのですが、bashで`+=`が使えるようになったのはいつからでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

更新履歴によると、bash 3.1からです。

bashの更新履歴(changelog)は[GNUから配布されているファイル](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/)の中の`NEWS`と`CHANGES`に入っています。自分の環境（Ubuntu 14.04)では`/usr/share/doc/bash`にもありました。Web上では[ここ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS)などにコピーがあります。

`NEWS`によると、

> This is a terse description of the new features added to bash-3.1 since
>   the release of bash-3.0.  As always, the manual page (doc/bash.1) is
>   the place to look for complete descriptions.
>
> 1.  New Features in Bash
>
> (中略)
>
> i.  The `+=' assignment operator (append to the value of a string or array) is
>       now supported for assignment statements and arguments to builtin commands
>       that accept assignment statements.

とのことです。

---

関連： ["Unable to find release notes for Bash -- Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793308/unable-to-find-release-notes-for-bash)